# How can I run a specific SAPUI5 control sample from Demo Kit locally?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I am looking up the [sample for the `sap.m.UploadCollection`](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.UploadCollection) control. I've downloaded and run the sample package locally using the following commands:

```bash
npm install
```

and then

```bash
ui5 serve -o index.html
```

I get the following error in console when navigating to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`:

> 2022-08-15 16:56:35.802600 Failed to load component for container container - ModuleError: Failed to resolve dependencies of 'sap/m/sample/UploadCollection/Page.controller.js'
> -> 'sap/m/MessageToast.js': failed to load 'sap/m/MessageToast.js' from ./resources/sap/m/MessageToast.js: script load error
> ModuleError: Failed to resolve dependencies of 'sap/m/sample/UploadCollection/Page.controller.js'

If I move the `Page.contoller.js` to a newly created controller folder and move the `Page.view.xml` to the newly created view folder, then a different error occurs.

**How can the downloaded sample project run locally?**

Comment: Btw. `sap.m.UploadCollection` is **deprecated since UI5 1.88**. Use [`sap.m.upload.UploadSet`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.upload.UploadSet) instead.

Comment: Just updated my answer below. Please consider accepting it to inform other readers that the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** most samples have now received fixes so that they can be started locally with `npm install && ui5 serve`. The issue mentioned in the question is no longer reproducible.

---

If a sample still cannot be started locally, ensure that the project is *UI5 Tooling* enabled. Follow ["Enabling an Existing Project"](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/stable/pages/GettingStarted/#enabling-an-existing-project).